# How can we check in PHP that we have permissions to file_put_contents() into a file?

Tags: php, file-permissions

When i am trying to execute [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) function to change the content of a text file,  it is showing me following error :

```
Warning: file_put_contents(somefile.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in path/to/changecontent.php
```

Is there any way to check whether we have permission to change a file contents or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`is_writable`](http://www.php.net/is_writable) to check if a file or directory is writable.